# Coding Standards for Android

Tags: android, xml, standards, constants

I have a constant value as shown below in my code.

```
static final int CONNECTION = 20000;
```

I need to maintain a xml file for constant values as we have for strings(string.xml)
(or an alternate way to store constants other than my java class)

please suggest an appropriate solution for this

Also, is there any document available for coding standards

Thanks.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Integer

Answer (score 1):

you can store this value as an integer resource like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer
        name="Connection"
        >20000</integer>
</resources>
```

for more information here is the link[link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Integer)

Answer (score 0):

you can store Integer in res/value like strings. see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Integer). From the doc you can see the example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer
        name="integer_name"
        >integer</integer>
</resources>
```

In this kind of cases I personally create another class to store all static final int.